# How to perform circle gesture operation on mobile device screen using appium for iOS

Tags: android, ios, selenium, jquery-mobile, appium

I’m trying to perform a **circle gesture operation on mobile device screen using appium**. I tried with **`swipe()`, `press("args").moveTo("args")`** and also tried using javascript executor method also. But not able to perform the circle gesture operation on mobile screen for iOS.

**Need to perform this circle gesture operation without loosing the touch in middle while performing this action from first point to last point.**

Is there any tool like **`AutoIT or Sikuli`** to perform this above gesture operation on mobile devices and can be executed in appium scripts using java in Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [touch actions](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions.md)!
I tried it on iOS and android real devices, it works fine. But you may need to play around a bit to get the right sets of coordinates and move parameters.

Comment: Hi Vvvaib, thanks for the reply. **My question is that whether we can perform complete circle gesture without loosing the touch on the screen till end point**. **`I tried this but getting coordinates out of screen error. And do you know how actually appium considers the coordinate points.`**

Comment: I think you can perform the whole gesture without loosing touch of the screen. Only issue is - you have to give lot many steps in the Touch action command to move smoothly pixel by pixel and perform the circle gesture. I know this because I made a custom zoom in zoom out function for my app. Coordinates at the top left of the screen are 0,0. If you go down Y increases and if you go towards Right- X increases. Bottom right  corner is - width of the device,height of the device. To get all the coordinates to make a circle - get coordinates of the circumference. Better use a maths formula.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310366/how-to-calculate-new-coordinates-on-a-circles-circumference-when-an-angle-is-gi

Comment: Thanks '@Vvvaib' finally it worked after all work around with coordinates.

Comment: @Rohith : Thanks for tag. will let you know if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a quick solution, here is my implementation based on the other comments in this thread:

```
public void SwipeArc(double centerX, double centerY, double radius, double startDegree, double degrees, int steps)
{
    //interpolate along the circumference of the circle
    double angle = degrees / steps;
    double prevX = centerX + radius * Math.Cos(startDegree * Math.PI / 180F); ;
    double prevY = centerY + radius * Math.Sin(startDegree * Math.PI / 180F);

    TouchAction circleTouch = new TouchAction(_Driver); //Your appium driver object here
    circleTouch.Press(prevX, prevY);

    for(int i = 1; i <= steps; ++i)
    {
        double newX = centerX + radius * Math.Cos((startDegree + angle * i) * Math.PI / 180F);
        double newY = centerY + radius * Math.Sin((startDegree + angle * i) * Math.PI / 180F);

        double difX = newX - prevX;
        double difY = newY - prevY;
        circleTouch.MoveTo(difX, difY);

        prevX = newX;
        prevY = newY;
    }

    circleTouch.Release();
    circleTouch.Perform();
}
```

This solution assumes the Appium server is expecting relative coordinates for each step, I'm not sure if this is the case for all Appium server versions.

Comment: how to select element?